# Compile time decorator pattern in C++ with templates

Tags: c++, c++11, template, template-meta-programming

I'm doing some high energy physics modelling in C++.  I have written code that implements class that score interactions of particles with detector material.

Here is a base class:

```
class XYZScorer: public virtual AbstractScorer{
public:

    XYZScorer(double material_rad_len=-1):
        AbstractScorer(material_rad_len){;}

    virtual void RegisterHit(const XYZHit hit)=0;

};
```

Function `RegisterHit` registers single interaction between particle and detector. There are many scorers in this program.

Since modeling experimental data is quite hard, I need to be able to add some features to these scorers and I'll need to be able to easily switch these features on and off. I decided to implement these features using a decorator pattern.  Here is decorator base class.

```
template <typename Scorer>
class ScorerDecorator: public virtual XYZScorer{

protected:
    Scorer scorer;
public:
    ScorerDecorator(Scorer scorer): XYZScorer(scorer.material_rad_len), scorer(scorer){;}
    virtual ~ScorerDecorator(){}

    virtual void SetEvent(size_t new_incident){
        scorer.SetEvent(new_incident);
    }

    virtual void CloseAfterRunEnd(){
        scorer.CloseAfterRunEnd();
    }
};
```

Here are two implementations of these decorators:

```
template <typename Scorer>
class FixZToFirstInteractionScorer: public virtual ScorerDecorator<Scorer>{
private:
    bool fixed_in_this_event=false;
    double position_of_first_intraction=0;
public:

    FixZToFirstInteractionScorer(Scorer scorer): ScorerDecorator<Scorer>(scorer){}
    virtual ~FixZToFirstInteractionScorer(){}

    virtual void SetEvent(size_t new_incident){
        fixed_in_this_event=false;
        ScorerDecorator<Scorer>::SetEvent(new_incident);
    }

    virtual void RegisterHit(const XYZHit hit){
        if(!fixed_in_this_event){
            fixed_in_this_event=true;
            position_of_first_intraction=hit.z;
        }
        XYZHit fixed_coords = hit;
        fixed_coords.z-=position_of_first_intraction;
        this->scorer.RegisterHit(fixed_coords);
    }

};
```

And another one:

```
template<typename Scorer>
class ApplyEnergyCutsScorer: public virtual ScorerDecorator<Scorer>{
    const double e_cut_energy;
public:
    ApplyEnergyCutsScorer(Scorer scorer):
        ScorerDecorator<Scorer>(scorer), e_cut_energy(GodObject::GetEcut()){}
    virtual ~ApplyEnergyCutsScorer(){}
inline bool accept(const XYZHit hit){
    double kin_energy = hit.GetParticleKineticEnergy();
    if(e_cut_energy < 0){
        return true;
    }
    if (kin_energy <0){
        throw new invariant_error("Energy less than zero --- normally it signifies that step wasnt passed to XYZHit");
    }
    if (kin_energy < e_cut_energy){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

virtual void RegisterHit(const XYZHit hit){
    if (accept(hit)){
        this->scorer.RegisterHit(hit);
    }
}

};
```

So far so good:

- Note that due to template usage and `scorer` not being a pointer there is no virtual function call here at all. This quite important for me because: `RegisterHit` function is called for every interaction of any particle with the detector (which is quite often), and having multiple virtual table lookups could be slow (I guess).
- I can wrap a class in multiple decorators, and compiler will unwrap and inline everyting (I checked that).

My problem is with instantiating these decorators, wrapping three of them in single method is ugly. Anyways here is the example (from production code):

```
template<typename Scorer>
std::shared_ptr<XYZScorer> InitializeAnyScorer(
        std::shared_ptr<AbstractGeometry> geometry, Scorer scorer, double cut_off_energy){
    if (!geometry->IsEnabled()){
        return std::shared_ptr<XYZScorer>(0);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<XYZScorer> result_scorer;
    if (!geometry->GetMoveZToFirstInteraction()){
        result_scorer = std::shared_ptr<ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<Scorer>>(
                 new ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<Scorer>(
                         scorer
                 )
             );
    }else{
        result_scorer = std::shared_ptr<FixZToFirstInteractionScorer<ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<Scorer>>>(
                new FixZToFirstInteractionScorer<ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<Scorer>>(
                    ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<Scorer>(
                            scorer
                )
            )
        );
    }

    return result_scorer;
}
```

How can I deal with ugliness of instantiating of my decorated scorers?

- Is there any better decorator pattern in C++ that is **performed compile time** (I want all decorated functions to be inlineable), and applicable to my problem?
- How can my decorated scorers be instantiate in a nicer way?  I was considering a variadict template function but I surrendered.

Ideally I'd like to be able to use something similar to:

```
std::shared_ptr<XYZScorer> ptr 
     = decorate(scorer, FixZToFirstInteractionScorer, ApplyEnergyCutsScorer);
```

**Non issues**

- Both my code and any solution can work in a single thread mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I might have a number of minor stylistic comments but this is not important. What is important is the desired function `decorate()`:

```
template <typename S>
using result = typename std::result_of <S>::type;

template <template <typename> class E, template <typename> class... D>
struct decorate_impl
{
    template <typename A, typename N = result<decorate_impl<D...>(A)>>
    E<N> operator()(A&& a) const
    {
        return E<N>(decorate_impl<D...>()(std::forward<A>(a)));
    }
};

template <template <typename> class E>
struct decorate_impl <E>
{
    template <typename A, typename N = typename std::decay<A>::type>
    E<N> operator()(A&& a) const { return E<N>(std::forward<A>(a)); }
};

template <template <typename> class E, template <typename> class... D, typename A>
std::shared_ptr <E<result<decorate_impl<D...>(A)>>)
decorate(A&& a)
{
    return std::make_shared <E<result<decorate_impl<D...>(A)>>>
        (decorate_impl<D...>()(std::forward<A>(a)));
}
```

which can be used like

```
std::shared_ptr<XYZScorer> ptr =
    decorate<FixZToFirstInteractionScorer, ApplyEnergyCutsScorer>(scorer);
```

This is very close to the desired syntax (maybe better), generic with respect to number and type of arguments, and inlinable.

Here is a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9a5c3425b18938b), where I've thrown some arbitrary code to fill in the missing pieces of your code so that the whole thing compiles.

### Attempt 2

---

I have now realized that the entire approach is wrong. We have a number of class templates and we want to apply them to a given object sequentially, constructing a nested object. To do this, we have a list of the class templates and we ask a single function `decorate()` to do the entire job for us, using recursion.

This is not right. The class templates themselves should not be used directly. We should have a helper function to wrap a given object into each class individually, exactly what `std::make_shared()` does for `std::shared_ptr` (similarly `make_tuple`, `make_pair` etc.). So here it is:

```
template <typename S>
using decay = typename std::decay<S>::type;

template <typename S>
FixZToFirstInteractionScorer<decay<S>> fixZToFirstInteraction(S&& scorer)
{
    return FixZToFirstInteractionScorer<decay<S>>(std::forward<S>(scorer));
}

template <typename S>
ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<decay<S>> applyEnergyCuts(S&& scorer)
{
    return ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<decay<S>>(std::forward<S>(scorer));
}

template<typename S>
std::shared_ptr<decay<S>> share(S&& scorer)
{
    return std::make_shared<decay<S>>(std::forward<S>(scorer));
}
```

to be used like

```
std::shared_ptr<XYZScorer> ptr =
    share(fixZToFirstInteraction(applyEnergyCuts(scorer)));
```

See [new live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1914c8fb75210177), where I have both approaches and a validation that they produce the same result. In fact, I've discovered a mistake in my first attempt, which I have now corrected.

I think this is cleaner and probably easier to use. Its implementation is easier to understand (it's not so "magical" as the first attempt) and certainly easier for the compiler (so, faster to compile). Each object is created at the right time when its type is known, and no recursion is needed to find all unknown return types of deeply nested function calls as with `decorate()`. Maybe I was carried away by the "desired syntax" and didn't see this immediately.

Of course, this means we have to write one more function for each new scorer class template. But all these functions are so small and similar. If we are very lazy we could even write a macro for them.

Note that in this case we are also constructing the outermost `Scorer` before making the `shared_ptr`, which we didn't in the first attempt. The reason is that otherwise we would need *two* functions for each class template, one returning an object on the stack and another a `shared_ptr`. In case `Scorer` is a large object, a move constructor will ensure that we don't loose performance with the unnecessary object.

### Attempt 3

---

Never giving up. [New live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5516d51ba4612b7).

Without `decorate()`, without any helper functions (except `share()`), just this:

```
std::shared_ptr<XYZScorer> ptr3 =
    share(FixZToFirstInteractionScorer<ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<Scorer>>(scorer));
```

It just works! Why? `FixZToFirstInteractionScorer<ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<Scorer>>` expects an `ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<Scorer>` argument and we give it just a `Scorer`. But an `ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<Scorer>` is *implicitly* constructed from the `Scorer`. All this happens automatically without touching the code, and will work under arbitrary nesting.

We could even write a new `decorate()` around this idea, which would be purely metaprogramming now. I may do this, or not.

Comment: Thanks! Would you care to elaborate how it works? Or is it some kind of patter I can read about (if so where).

Comment: Wow. That is some impressive template magic! Wish I could more than +1 this.

Comment: Agree with @Corbin this is mind blowing!

Comment: @jb Well, I don't know where to start elaborating :-) There are a number of techniques being used here. From more to less important, you can look at [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_templates), [perfect forwarding](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_07.html), [alias templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), and type traits [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of), [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay). I'll try to add more in the answer tomorrow.

Comment: @jb Also note I've edited the code to make it much simpler than in my original post, and I now use `std::make_shared` as suggested by [Corbin](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47087/39083) (thanks).

Comment: @jb I added another solution which is much simpler, and I think this is the correct one. If you are happy with this, then maybe I am spared from explaining the previous "magical" one ;-)

Comment: @jb And a third solution...

Comment: @iavr Hrmm, do you think giving up explicit type safety is worth the convenience? What if you accidentally pass a Scorer when you think you're passing a ApplyEnergyCutsScorer to a function and one is implicitly created? Not such great behavior then. (I actually should have noticed the non-explicit 1 parameter constructor in my review :/)

Comment: @Corbin I don't know, it depends on class design. In the current design, scorers behave like tuples, in the sense that you can embed one into another. You can have an `S1<S2<S3<S4>>>>` constructed by an `S1<S2<S3<S4>>>>` (copy/move), `S2<S3<S4>>>` (current intent), `S3<S4>>` (implicit), or `S4` (implicit), and you get the same result. With more classes, maybe one should be more careful and make constructors explicit. It depends on whether there are any constraints.

Comment: @Corbin In the previous example, you cannot construct an `S1<S2<S3<S4>>>>` by some unrelated `S6<S5>` or `S5`. You still have this protection, I don't know if this is enough.

Comment: @jb In case you choose solution 3 and you have no problems as discussed with Corbin *and* you prefer the `decorate()` syntax, let me know and I'll write one. It will be simpler than that of solution 1.

Comment: @iavr thank you one more time. Maybe one more clarification --- what is the role of the `share` function? From what I can tell it does nothing more that wrap `make_shared`, but when I tried to use just make_shared but the compiler complained.

Comment: @jb [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) takes as 1st template parameter the type of object to construct. If you already have an object and want to copy/move it, `share()` above takes the type of the given object, strips off references and cv-qualifiers by [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay), and if `T` is the raw type, calls `std::make_shared<T>` on the given object. It just makes things slightly simpler as an interface, but takes an additional move operation that is most probably optimized out.

Answer (score 7):

I need a bit to look into a cleaner decorator pattern, but three technicalities immediately jump out at me.

---

Accepting a user defined value as const implies that your methods should probably be taking const-references. `void f(const T)` will make a copy of the value passed to it. `void f(const T&)` will not, yet it maintains the restriction that `T` cannot be mutated. Unless there's something I'm missing, I can't see why you're taking all of the `XYZHit` by const value.

The rules can be a bit more complicated, but in most cases:

- If you want to mutate an object and have the changes visible from the outside, accept by reference.
- If you want to mutate an object and not have the changes visible from the outside, accept by value (allowing you to change the copy, not the passed value).
- If you do not want to mutate the object, accept by const-reference.

---

Another issue I immediately see is that you're instantiating `shared_ptr` directly whereas you should always use `make_shared`.

There are certain exception safety issues with `shared_ptr` in the general case (for example: what if you have `shared_ptr(new T, new R)` and the `new T` succeeds then `new R` throws? `R` will leak).

More importantly for your case though, `make_shared` exhibits better performance since it can roll the reference count (which has to be heap allocated) and the object allocation into the same allocation. Not only does this save an allocation, but it can also improve cache coherency depending on usage patterns.

As a bonus, it's also a tiny bit less repetitive (though not meaningfully -- it just removes one duplicated type). For example, your biggest instantiation becomes:

```
std::make_shared<FixZToFirstInteractionScorer<ApplyEnergyCutsScorer<Scorer>>>(ApplyEnergyCutsScorer(scorer));
```

---

When you're not taking (partial) ownership of a `shared_ptr`, you should take it by const-reference. This allows you avoid making an unnecessary copy of the pointer which will in turn do significant bookkeeping work behind the scenes only to undo it when the function returns. Since `InitializeAnyScorer` has no interest in becoming a partial owner of `geometry`, there's no reason to make copy of the `shared_ptr` when a const reference will do.

---

Also, on a bit of a design tangent, are you sure you need `shared_ptr`? I'm a bit afraid you've only used it because it's convenient to have copy semantics. If you only have one object or scope owning something, you can use a `unique_ptr` and pass it by const-reference instead of making copies. If you actually need shared ownership semantics, then yes, of course go with `shared_ptr`. If there is single ownership though, `unique_ptr` has much, much better performance than `shared_ptr`.

Comment: You are right about most of things. 

This my first project in C++, really. I took some courses 5+ years ago, but from then only highter level stuff.  When I decided to used ``shared_ptr`` I was just baffled by the complexity of move semantics.

Maybe a simple clarification is shared_ptr::operator-> slower than unique_ptr::operator->, or copying is more expensive. 

I also agree that I probably should use XYZHit&, but It should be irrevelant in case of performance as it is optimized out ;). I'll check it however.

Comment: @jb. Dereferencing should be the same speed for both shared_ptr and unique_ptr. Dereferencing should be just the same as dereferencing a normal pointer provided the compiler does its magic and inlines `operator->` or `operator*` call. The performance hit comes from shared_ptr doing a lot more work than `unique_ptr` to keep track of meta data about the managed object. `unique_ptr` is just a glorified RAII container.

Comment: shared_ptr, however, has to know how many copies of itself exist and only destruct the object when the count reaches 0 (and it has to 0 out weak_ptr). What complicates it even further is that shared_ptr supports multithreading, meaning incrementing and decrementing the count is not a simple add or sub, but instead requires a much slower atomic add/sub, quite a bit of extra work over unique_ptr's nothing.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate more on (mentioned in the other answer) possible problems with non explicit constructors.

Comment: @jb. I will edit in a more detailed explanation when I have time, but the short version of it is that 1 argument non-explicit constructors allow potentially unexpected conversions to happen at the cost of type safety. For example: `struct S { S(int x); };` and `void f(S s);`. Would you expect `f(3)` to compile? It does because S can be implicitly constructed from an int. In some situations this is very useful and the semantics are pretty natural. In others, it can cause very subtle bugs. Due to the risk for misunderstandings, I tend to always avoid implicit constructors.